# What is the COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE xcode build settings default value?

Tags: xcode-build-settings

There is Default, YES, NO, but what is the Default value? is YES or NO?

https://xcodebuildsettings.com/#compiler_index_store_enable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: it defaults to `YES`.

Based on empirical observations and logical conclusions (hah), this property always defaults to `YES`, as of today.

This setting is what enables indexing of features such as autocompletion and rich navigation in Xcode. So when you build the project via Xcode, it will certainly be true, because it will seize the opportunity that the project is already being built to create that indexing for us.

One would expect that this property should default to `NO` when building via CLI (i.e. `xcodebuild` command line), however, as reported by Peter Stainberger [here](https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1100406730163245057?s=20&t=ypXnRP-r-6m3U7SsdNh3Ew), that's not the case:

[image]

So yeah, as of today, this always defaults to `YES`, however, it could be changed in the future.